# Excel - Pull bottom 3 from list excluding 0's

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I've seen similar questions on here and SO, but nothing that matches my question or I can tweak enough to make work. Sorry I cannot post the pic here, still waiting for reputation to grow.

As you can see in the picture, I am trying to pull the top 3 and bottom 3 accounts from the table in A1.  My problem lies with the bottom 3.  I am trying to omit any rows with 0 in column B, and only have it pull #s that are >0.  I assume an IF function somewhere in there would work, but I have not been able to get it to.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]Can’t do any trial or testing but there is the SMALL() function : specify the range and the position number , to avoid zeroes - if you count the number of zeros ie 4 for example and then set the small function to get positions 5, 6and 7...

Edit so cells D5 D6 and D7 get the 3 smallest using the result of the countif and the value in c5 c6 and c7...

Comment: So your formula would be `=SMALL($B$2:$B$11,COUNTIF($B$2:$B$11,0)+D7)`?

Answer (score 0):

Use Aggregate:

Put:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,$B$2:$B$11/($B$2:$B$11>0),D7)
```

In F7 and copy down.

Then use the same formula in E as above to match the return with the name.

Comment: Scott's is nicer than mine :) but what works works...

Comment: @SolarMike I like my version of your approach better as it is not an array formula and does everything in one formula, but your approach is better.

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks for the compliment - that means a lot ! Cheers.

Comment: Gives the OP several options then .